# How to delete characters that appear more than once in a string

Tags: javascript

```
for(var i=0; i <array.length;i++){
    for(var j=1; j<=array.length;j++) 
    if(array[i]==array[j])  array.splice(j,1)
}
```

Have been trying using the code above but it just deletes every other char.

Comment: you're matching the same character make sure j != to i before deleting

Answer (score 4):

My way would be to convert it into a `Set` and then to an `Array` and then `join` to get the final `Stirng` back.

```js
let a = 'aaabbbcdddd';
console.log(Array.from(new Set(a)).join(''));
```

Answer (score 2):

Straightforward method with [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`...`)  by utilising uniqueness property of [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
let a = 'aaabbbcdddd';
console.log([...new Set(a)].join(''));
```

> The `Set` object lets you store unique values of any type

We are giving string(which is iterable) to initiate the `Set`, which will remove all duplicates from it. Then we are converting it back to an array with `Spread syntax` (`...`). Finally, `join` the array back together to make it a string.

Comment: I like this one more than my own answer. I really need to remember those fancy js syntaxes. Just a pointer though. The set constructor takes an iterable, String is already an iterable. You don't need to spread it.

Comment: Great catch @AmitDas! It just reduced the answer to half!!

Answer (score 0):

Your iterators `i` and `j` will incorrectly overlap. You should instead start your `j` iteration at `i+1`.

```js
let str = 'the hippos are singing';
let array = [...str];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  for (var j = i + 1; j <= array.length; j++)
    if (array[i] === array[j])
      array.splice(j, 1)
}
console.log(array.join(''));
```